# how to authenticate `com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery` with service account

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-api-java-client

I want to use this library

`com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery`

as in the example:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api

However I want to authenticate the `BigQuery` client with service account.

How can I do this?

I see only a default credentials way.

```
  BigQuery bigquery =
                new BigQueryOptions.DefaultBigqueryFactory().create(BigQueryOptions.defaultInstance());
```

Answer (score 12):

Try using setCredentials and ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream while building the service.

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
    .setCredentials(
       ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
         new FileInputStream("your_json_service_keyfile.json"))
    )
    .build().getService()
```

This ought to be better documented in Google's API doc.

Hope it helps, it's my first answer on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: you are the captain. this should be accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Beware that as per [Issue #3535](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/3535), the project ID may not be set correctly by `setCredentials` alone ("Missing project ID" error) and thus should be set explicitly using `setProjectId`.

E.g.

```
   ServiceAccountCredentials credentials;
   File credentialsPath = new File("/pathToJSONfile/SOME_NAME.json");

   try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
      credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
   }

   BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
         .setCredentials(credentials)
         .setProjectId(credentials.getProjectId())
         .build().getService();
```

Comment: thank you for the issue link but that issue got closed

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am really surprised and frustrated by the lack of google documentation and outdated samples. Almost all the sample in goodle console and git are out of date as they havent been updated with latest changes to libraries..